# Excluding in Live HTTP Headers plugin for Firefox

Tags: regex, firefox, http-headers

I am trying to exclude gmail's requests from Live Http headers, but I cant
seem to get the exclude reg ex to work.

My exclude regex is this: `.gif$|.jpg$|.ico$|.css$|.js$|.*mail.google.com.*`

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem and its soultion was stupid simple:

- do you have enabled the check box ("exclude URL by RegExp" (or similar - I have only the german version))?

*Hint: you do need to add the `.*` at start and end of your expression, because the request will be excludes if it **contains** the pattern (is must not match the complate url).*

Answer (score 0):

I think. You sould use "\." to catch a dot. Dot without slash is any symbol.
Like this:

\.gif$|\.jpg$|\.ico$|.css$|\.js$|.*mail\.google\.com.*

Comment: If you'll post the example of requests which you try to exclude I'll try to help you better.